# Can this 'aboard' be replaced by 'onboard'?

Tags: synonyms

If the *aboard* is postposed, can it be replaced by *onboard* and have the same meaning?

“a jetliner with 93 people **aboard**”

(This is from an English-Korean dictionary and has no full sentence.)

Comment: No. But you can replace it with the two-word form **on board**.

Comment: A good English dictionary such as [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) or [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/) will tell you the difference between *aboard* and *onboard* much faster than we can. If you are still confused you may edit your question to focus on just where your uncertainty lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean *on board* and if that's the case, then yes, you can replace one with the other. According to NOAD and OED, *on board* means:

> on or in a ship, aircraft, or other vehicle. • informal onto a team or group as a member: *the need to bring on board a young.*

And *aboard*:

> on or into (a ship, aircraft, train, or other vehicle): [ as adv. ] : *the plane crashed, killing all 158 people aboard* | figurative : *he came aboard as IBM's new chairman* | [ as prep. ] : *climbing aboard the yacht.*